# iOS: Can't save image in HEIC format if width or height is 1px

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, heic

Here is reproduction code for Xcode Playground:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

let f = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
f.scale = 1.0

let size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 1)
let image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size, format: f).image { rendererContext in
    UIColor.green.setFill()
    rendererContext.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
}

let tempDirURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory(), isDirectory: true)
var tempFileURL = tempDirURL.appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString)
tempFileURL = tempFileURL.appendingPathExtension("heic")

guard let imageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(tempFileURL as CFURL, AVFileType.heic as CFString, 1, nil)
    else { fatalError("unable to create CGImageDestination") }

CGImageDestinationAddImage(imageDestination, image.cgImage!, nil)

let result = CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDestination)
print(result)
```

If width or height is 1px, `CGImageDestinationFinalize` returns false and file is not created.

If height and width is at least 2px, image is saved without errors.

The same issue exists if I save using CIImage methods.

Comment: If I try to save the HEIC image in Preview app in mac with width and height as 1px, it throws the error , the document could not be saved. May be 2px * 2px is the minimum size of the HEIC image.

Comment: @VinayakaSY, good point. I googled but haven't found any specification about this limitation, if it exists.

Comment: yes right, even i googled, did not get any documents regarding the image specifications .